# Do iPhones still send packets when they are completely shutdown?

Tags: ios, wireshark, iphone, arp-spoofing

Do iPhones (or just a smart phones in general) send packets when they are fully shutdown? I have heard that they do, but I have not been able to verify such a claim. In an effort to investigate, I ARP Poisoned my own iPhone (legally on my own network) and monitored the packets via Wireshark on my computer, but once I shutdown the iPhone there were no more packets being sent or received. I am assuming that is because the ARP poisoning only works when the device is on the same network as you--whereas I would presume a shutdown iPhone disconnects from its current Wifi connection upon shutdown. Is that correct? Or is it truly not sending any packets? If they do send packets when they are shutdown then how would I go about sniffing those packets to see what it is all doing?

Comment: I don't know if all do or not, but classically it would be on the cellular side. You would need a spectrum analyzer to just detect it, and a cell tower simulator to actually analyze the content. **If** it sends any kind of network packet at start-up or shut-down, you could see it in the network traffic. Playing with ARP poisoning unnecessarily complicates.

Comment: A phone connects to 2 different networks. You only checked one.

Comment: Some smartphones have UHF chip which emits beacon signals for nearby UHF enabled devices so that it can be tracked even if it's off.

Comment: @defalt iOS [uses Bluetooth LE for this](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2019/06/05/how-does-apple-privately-find-your-offline-devices/), but as far as I know it doesn't operate when the phone is completely turned off.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question of security, and more a question of definitions of terms. I would argue that when a device is still sending packets, then it is *by definition* not "completely shutdown", and that when is "completely shutdown", then it is *by definition* not still sending packets.